Add-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation
I need your help. I am trying to create an assets library and always get the following error:

Add-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

I am already registered as site admin and everyone except external users has read permission, I just don't know what to do.
Does anyone know what to do?


Try using SharePoint tenant administrator account (only site admin permissions are not enough for this). Check: Create an Organization Assets Library in SharePoint Online. Let me know if it works for you.

You have to use an account with Global Administrator or SharePoint Administrator role in Microsoft 365 to create an organization assets library in your SharePoint tenant.
Check this documentation for learning more about these roles: About the SharePoint Administrator role in Microsoft 365.
Only site admin / site collection administrator (SCA) permissions are not enough for creating an organization assets library.
References:

Create an Organization Assets Library in SharePoint Online
Register SharePoint Document Library as an Organization Assets Library using PowerShell
Create an organization assets library


Same error as in the picture above. I am registered as site administrator, website owner and owner.
When I run "Get-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary", I also get the same error.
Is it possible that this is because I am doing this on my private laptop? I still have all admin rights in the Admincenter.

When I try to enter "Install-Module PnP.PowerShell", Windows asks me with which program I want to install it...

When you are connecting to admin center site, is it asking you for login or is it automatically logging in using saved credentials? Make sure it asks you for login and you use the correct admin credentials.

I have found the solution with the support: I had too many administrator rights in the Admin Center. I only need the "global administrator"

Great, glad it worked for you.
